# How to forward UDP traffic from IPv4 to IPv6?

Tags: networking, ipv6, forwarding, socat

I have a local Server that only has an IPv6 Adress on which i want to host a Minecraft Server for my friends and myself. The Problem is that some of them don't have an v6 adress.
I am currently using [socat](https://github.com/craSH/socat) to forward everything on the ports i need (HTTP, HTTPS, 25565 for MC). 
For TCP forwarding it works fine like this: 
`sudo socat TCP4-LISTEN:80,fork,su=nobody TCP6:[MYIP]:80`
but UDP doesn't work which I use like this: 
`sudo socat UDP4-RECVFROM:25565,fork,su=nobody UDP6-SENDTO:[MYIP]:25565`
I also saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1503996/socat-ipv4-to-ipv6-routing) which also didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me.
(Although, I would be inclined to use 2001:db8: for the start of sample addresses.)

So now you may need to troubleshoot.  Sniff traffic (e.g., tcpdump, Wireshark).  Problems can include firewalls, software like SOCAT not supporting UDP, server software not supporting IPv6, and others.  Your question provided some details but didn't narrow this down further, and more detail may be needed to get very specific in the suggestions.

An alternative: give them IPv6 addresses.  (See tunnelbroker.net for a free option.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, When I viewed all the traffic on port 25565 I found that there is nothing coming in so I changed the Serverport to 80 which works fine. Now I just have to figure out where exactly the port is blocked... And I totally forgot to edit out my IP from the commads, so thanks for the hint as well.